# I want to execute my below code as synchronous , by order in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var job = new cronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
    //find and send message using cron job

    Quicksms.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'phoneno', 'sender', 'message', 'isSent'],
        raw: true
    }).then(data => {
        console.log('data:', data);
        // var filteredData = datas.filter(data => data.isSent === 0);
        // console.log('filteredData:', filteredData);
        // for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // if (data.isSent === 0) {
        var uri = '/api/user=test&password=test&sender=' +
            data.sender + '&SMSText=' + data.message + '&GSM=' + data.phoneno;
        var sms = encodeURI(uri);
        var options = {
            host: 'test.com',
            port: 80,
            path: sms,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        http.request(options, function (res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            });
        }).end();


        //update into 1 true:
        Quicksms.update({
            isSent: 'true'
        }, {
            where: {
                id: data.id
            }
        })
        // }
        //  }


        //store in log
        QuicksmsLog.create({
            phoneno: data.phoneno,
            sender: data.sender,
            message: data.message,
            isSent: data.isSent
        }).then(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log("successfully stored in log");
            } else {
                console.log("failed");
            }
        })


        //destroy message after sending
        Quicksms.destroy({
            where: {
                isSent: 1
            }
        }).then(delData => {
            console.log('cronJob deleted successfully.', delData);
        });
    });
}, function () {
    console.log('DelCron Job finished.');
}, true, 'Asia/Calcutta');
```

Above code is working as async order
Async order :

1.Quicksms.findone

2.Quicksms.Delete

3.Quicksms.Update

4.Quicksmslogs.Create

This one working as async , i want to work this functions as order !

How to do that  in synchronous way? help me

What is the use of async task? in nodejs, I am a newbie! help me.

Comment: You can use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

Comment: Can you help me and post some answers? i dont know how to do, i am a newbie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using async await operation. Try to run the below code.

```
var job = new cronJob('* * * * * *', async function () {
    //find and send message using cron job

    await Quicksms.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'phoneno', 'sender', 'message', 'isSent'],
        raw: true
    }).then(data => {
        console.log('data:', data);
        // var filteredData = datas.filter(data => data.isSent === 0);
        // console.log('filteredData:', filteredData);
        // for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // if (data.isSent === 0) {
        var uri = '/api/user=test&password=test&sender=' +
            data.sender + '&SMSText=' + data.message + '&GSM=' + data.phoneno;
        var sms = encodeURI(uri);
        var options = {
            host: 'test.com',
            port: 80,
            path: sms,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        http.request(options, function (res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            });
        }).end();


        //update into 1 true:
        await Quicksms.update({
            isSent: 'true'
        }, {
            where: {
                id: data.id
            }
        })
        // }
        //  }


        //store in log
        await QuicksmsLog.create({
            phoneno: data.phoneno,
            sender: data.sender,
            message: data.message,
            isSent: data.isSent
        }).then(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log("successfully stored in log");
            } else {
                console.log("failed");
            }
        })


        //destroy message after sending
        await Quicksms.destroy({
            where: {
                isSent: 1
            }
        }).then(delData => {
            console.log('cronJob deleted successfully.', delData);
        });
    });
}, function () {
    console.log('DelCron Job finished.');
}, true, 'Asia/Calcutta');
```

Comment: Looks nice ! @Pavan

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of achieving synchronous process, using Promise. It looks like those methods above are [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instances, and I will assue they are so. In a traditional way, you can make a [promise chain](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) out of multiple promise instances. I will make a sample code below so that you can see how it works. Also, if you are familiar with ES7 syntax, you can use [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await) too. However, since you are new to node.js, I will leave an answer for the former approach. Check below. Hope this will help you!

```
Quicksms.findone((...args)=>{
  ...
  return Quicksms.Delete(...args);
})
.then((...args)=>{
  ...
  return Quicksms.Update(...args);

})
.then((...args)=>{
  ...
  return Quicksmslogs.Create(...args);
})
.then((...args)=>{
  ...
  console.log("Your jobs has been completed in order!");
})
.catch(err=>console.error(err))
```